# Where is Wakanda in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018

Where is Wakanda located, according to the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

The Marvel Atlas places it in West Africa, but having watched *Black Panther* it seemed to be much further southeast

[image: Wakanda from the Marvel Atlas]

Comment: I thought it bordered Zamunda, actually.

Comment: The fact that they speak !Xhosa would put it in South/Southeastern Africa, but even the southern border of Uganda is a mite far for their clicks. (Not that it really matters, I was just surprised to hear !Xhosa in a country supposedly in East Africa).

Comment: somewhere near Nambia?

Comment: I also wondered this. There's a map in *Black Panther* (possibly during one of the newsreel sequences?) which shows Wakanda's location in the context of a map of Africa. Hoping someone can post a shot of that frame.

Comment: Interesting map, but based on what's been seen in the comics, let alone the film, utterly wrong. Wakanda has never been portrayed as being in the Sahara or the Sahel, which has a noted lack of forests.

Answer (score 33):

### This is actually a little unclear, but it appears to border Uganda in East Africa.

The issue is that the first time we see a reference to the location of Wakanda is in *Captain America: Civil War*.

It is located on the Northeastern edge of Uganda.

[image: Civil War Map]

But the more recently released *Marvel's Black Panther: The Art of the Movie* alters this. The location is now on the Southwestern edge of Uganda.

[image: Art book]

Comment: The second map doesn't really add up. Lake Kivu is on the border between Rwanda and DRC: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=8/-1.771/30.509 and its shape is different than what portrayed above. Also, it's not clear what the eastern lake is. This is not a plausible map by any means - which may well be intentional.

Comment: @Simone: It's a fictional country. Of course they're going to have to shift borders to make it fit. It's not like there's a Wakanda-shaped hole in the ground in real life.

Comment: Actually according to the Civil War map it's in the northwestern edge of Kenya. The lake in the middle of "Wakanda" is Lake Turkana which is wholly in Kenya.

Comment: Of course, of course. In a way, they could have cut a piece from each bordering state and let us think that there's a remote region that has not been explored, and that's where Wakanda is. On the other hand, though, being too plausible would probably mean trouble with people living in that exact area...

Answer (score 17):

According to the map from *Civil War*, it is closer to Uganda (image taken from [the Wikia](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/File:Wakanda_On_The_Map_(CACW).png)).

[image: map as seen in the movie]

Here is a map of Africa for reference in the continent:
[image: map of Africa]

Answer (score 10):

According to the MCU, Wakanda is located in the Eastern part of Africa (somewhere in the region between Kenya and Tanzania in the real world). Here is a video of *Iron Man 2*'s ending where Nick Fury approaches Stark with the Avengers initiative.

Pause the video at 1:17. There is a marker in Africa which is Wakanda.

[image: marker on the map]

Comment: I'm sorry, can you find anything where there is something actually identifying that location as Wakanda? It's the right vicinity, but I can't read anything on that screen in the video.

Comment: @phantom42: Though I agree that _by itself_ the screenshot isn't conclusive proof; it does seem fair to assume that given the other proof (putting it somewhere near Uganda, which is where the marker is) and Marvel's tendency to add Easter eggs like that; the marker is indeed in reference to Wakanda.

Comment: You can also see it at 0:52.

Answer (score 1):

We now know that MCU Wakanda has a seacoast (off of which the seaquake mentioned in "Endgame" occurred), so all these maps must be wrong. Or perhaps Wakanda conquered some territory during the five years of global chaos caused by the Snap. Do they still give out No-Prizes?

Comment: If you could [edit] in The relevant quote and edit this to read more as an answer than a reply it would be a lot better. SFF isn’t like a discussion forum but rather each answer should be standalone in answering the question.

Answer (score -3):

If you look at the map in the opening scene of *Black Panther*, Wakanda seems to be taking the place of south-western Uganda on a real map.  So it's bordered by Uganda, Rwanda and Congo... and probably a bit of Tanzania.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  you can make this answer much stronger if you can get a screen-shot of that image from the movie and [edit] it into your answer.